# Not comparing string in Rust

Tags: rust

I have taken the input from user but when i am trying to compare, it does not enter the if or else if block . Instead, it goes to else block

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let small_coffee = 2;
    let medium_coffee = 4;
    let large_coffee = 6;

    let mut total_price = 0;

    let mut user_choice = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_choice).ok().expect("Eror");

    if user_choice == "1" {
        total_price += small_coffee;
    } else if user_choice == "2" {
        total_price += medium_coffee;
    } else if user_choice == "3" {
        total_price += large_coffee;
    } else {
        println!("Sorry! Invalid Choice");
    }

    println!("Your total bill amounted to : {}$", total_price);
}
```

Comment: Thank you brother for taking out the time to answer the Question . . . but i am getting the problem using VSCode on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function will read bytes from the underlying stream until the newline delimiter (the 0xA byte) or EOF is found. Once found, all bytes up to, and including, ***the delimiter (if found) will be appended to buf.***

Use [`trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim), `let input = user_choice.trim();`